# Limit at origin of function of two variables

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

How I can show that this limit does not exist at $(0,0)$ using some path.
$f(x,y)=2xy/(x^{2}+y)$ where function has value $0$ at origin. Looking at graph of function,I got there's some parabola of type $y^{2}=-ax$, which will create some problem, but I am stuck.

Comment: You are right with your intuition indeed the trick is to take $x=t$ and $y=-t^2$ in order to appoach the origin along the parabola $-x=y^2$. But the points on the parabola are excluded from the domain therefore we need to add a negligible term to $y$ in order to stay in the domain, that is $y=-t^2+t^4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

- $x=0 \implies f(0,y)=0$
- $x=t \quad y=t^4-t^2 \quad t\to 0^+$ $$\implies \frac{2xy}{x^2+y}=\frac{2t^5-2t^3}{t^2+t^4-t^2}=\frac{2t^2-2}{t}\to-\infty$$